# Android APK won't generate when doing run

Tags: android, linux, eclipse, apk

I have several android application and sample code I have downloaded/coded. All these are in my eclipse workspace. I have installed all the required plugins/images for android development on eclipse.

The projects compile perfectly you you do Build (I get "Build Sucess!") and will generate an APK package when doing an Export signed/Unsigned.

The problem is here:
if I do run in either an emulator or connected device I get:

```
Error generating final archive: java.io.EOFException
```

With:

```
Location : Unkown
Type : Android Packaging Problem
```

I am running openSUSE 12.1 with Eclipse 4.2 (tried also 3.5 but no luck)
Latest ADT and android SDK
Tried compiling for all android versions (1 to 16)

Please help because I am tired or doing export and adb install to place the package on my device.

Comment: C:\Documents and Setting\User\Local Settings\Application Data\android\debug.keystore . delete this file and try again.

Comment: If that doesn't resolve it, have you tried installing the apk manually rather than using dev tools?

Comment: @abbas save my day! is that a bug ?

Comment: i dont think its because of bug in your code. debug.keystore will be created by android automatically.

Answer (score 4):

Delete the following file and try again.

> C:\Documents and Setting\User\Local Settings\Application
>   Data\android\debug.keystore .

Comment: Thank you very much abbas.aniefa!
It helped me a lot. You saved my day. In the case of windows 7 this file is located at C:\Users\<UserName>\.android\debug.keystore